# Open and close vcl form

Tags: delphi, forms

Right now i have 2 forms. On Form1 i open up Form2 like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form2: TForm2;
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Form2);
  Form2.ShowModal;
  Form2.Free;
end;
```

Now i want to close the Form2 with a button on it. So i tried

```
procedure TForm2.cancelBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Close;
end;`
```

But that only gives me Access violation error when i click that button. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to do

```
procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

and, if `TForm2` contains a OK button, this should have the `ModalResult` property set to `mrOK` at design-time. Use the object inspector to set this. You probably also want to set `Default` to `True`. Now you can 'click' the OK button by pressing the Enter key on your keyboard!

In addition, if there is a Cancel button in the dialog, this should have `ModalResult` set to `mrCancel` and `Cancel` set to `True`. Now you can 'click' the Cancel button by pressing the Escape key on your keyboard!

A button with a `ModalResult` value will automatically close a modal dialog box.

Comment: @Jörn: 'Should' is a pretty strong word. But you definitely 'could' use `nil` as the owner.

Comment: @Andreas:  When an owner is passed to the constructor, it is the owner that should be responsible for the freeing of the component.
If the owner is omitted, the execution of the constructor and destructor will be faster, because the owner doesn't need to maintain the ownership of the component.

Comment: ...continued:  The owner actually iterates through all it's owned components in the create method and in the free method to maintain the ownership.  Ie. that if you pass Application as the owner, the constructor will iterate trough all components on every form that is owned by the application during create and during free.
Try to measure the creation of 1000 components with nil vs self/application and see the difference...

Comment: ...continued: Another problem arises if the owner is freed before you free the component yourself int th finally block (eg an user closes the form).  The owner will then free all the owned items including the one you just created.  You will probably get an AV in the finally block when you tries to free the component that is already freed.

Comment: @Jörn: Yes, I know all that. I don't think that the difference in performance is that significant, though. You seldom have more than one modal form at a time (not a thousand!). And surely it is pretty unlikely that  `TForm1` is freed while the `TForm2` is modal?!

Comment: @Andreas, I totally agree in this case, of course :) And yes, this issue is more important for components than forms - especially the modal ones... I just like to be consistent all over.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - You are one of the Top3 favorite Delphi guys on the whole Internet. Thanks for making the Delphi world better. I hope you will get well soon!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Since the form is showing modally the correct solution is to set `ModalResult := mrCancel` in your button click handler. The shortcut is to set the `ModalResult` property of the button to `mrCancel` and then you don't even need the event handler.

---

Note that your form is being created incorrectly.  You are passing the unassigned variable `Form2` as the `Owner` parameter to the constructor. I expect this is the cause of the access violation.

You should pass another form, `Application` or `nil`, for example.  In fact in this case you may as well pass nil so that the code should read:

```
Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
try
  Form2.ShowModal;
finally
  Form2.Free;
end;
```

If you pass an owner then the form will be destroyed when the owner is destroyed. Since you are destroying it yourself, you don't need to pass an owner.

That said, it is sometimes useful to set the owner, for example if you are using one of the `Position` property values that sets the form's position based on the owner's position. If so then I recommend passing `Self` in this instance which is a `TForm1` object reference.

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers discuss other ways to solve your problem.

I am going to point out the cause of the problem.

You have two variables named Form2.  One contains the form and the other is uninitialized most likely Nil.    The cause of the A/V is because your accessing the Nil variable.

When working with in a class you should avoid using the variable name of the class instead you can reference it's members directly such as calling `Close;` without referencing the variable.   To keep things clear you can also prefix it with `self.`  so replace `form2.close;` with `self.close;`

Comment: if Form2 was nil when the constructor was called then there would be no error.

Comment: There are two sections of code.   Form2 in the second section of code could not be the same variable.   I suspect that is the global variable created by default.

Answer (score 1):

In your second code, you're already in form 2, so you would only need to do

```
procedure TForm2.cancelBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

If in your first code you created a variable you didnt use the generic Form2 variable made as a public variable in the form, its not then allocated to the form you called. So it will give errors. If at the top of the unit, you removed the "var Form2: TForm2;" line, you'd see it complain about the lack of variable for that line, change it to close, it will go away and so will your error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already resolved that question or created a new code to avoid the problem, but what I think is happening (and you didn't showed all your code to confirm) is that you created bad code on the OnActivate main form event.

When you exit the second form, you return to your mainform and it "actvates" again.
Probably you manipulated an object that do not exists anymore.

Comment: I will give you one point every time I will see your name on SO. I love it!!!! (therefore +1 here).